# Any relationship between the parts of speech of the word to which a prefix can apply and of the word from which a prefix is derived?

Tags: prefix, compound-verb, compound-noun

Keller's Learn to Read Latin says

> **Compound Verbs, Prefixes, Assimilation, and Vowel Weakcning**
>
> A compound verb (< compono, put together) is a verb formed from the
> combination of a simple, or uncompounded, verb and a prefix. A prefix
> (< praefigo, fasten in front) is a unit of meaning added to the
> beginning of a word to produce another word. **Most prefixes in Latin
> are derived from adverbs, and many prefixes have corresponding
> prepositions.** A prefix has a basic meaning, and the meaning of a
> compound Latin verb can sometimes be deduced by combining the meaning
> of the simple verb with the basic meaning of the prefix. Thus accédo
> is a compound formed by the addition of the prefix ad- (to, toward) to
> cedo, cedere, cessi, cessum “go,” and this compound means “go toward,”
> “approach.” However, the meanings of many compound verbs cannot be
> deduced in this way, and for this reason compound verbs are given as
> separate vocabulary entries. The basic meanings of the prefixes used
> to form compounds are given in Appendix P.

Regarding

> Most prefixes in Latin are derived from adverbs, and many prefixes have
> corresponding prepositions.

Can a prefix be derived from a preposition instead of an adverb?

Based on Oxford Latin Dictionary, how can I figure out from which part of speech (prep. or adv.) the following two prefixes are derived?

praeter-

[image]

trans-

[image]

Is there any relationship between the part of speech of the word to which a prefix can apply and the part of speech of the word from which a prefix is derived?

- Does a prefix derived from a preposition apply only to a noun to form a compound word? Is the compound word most likely an adverb?
- Does a prefix derived from an adverb apply only to a verb or adjective to form a compound verb or adjective/adverb?

Comment: I'm not sure why they say that. The vast majority of prefixes (in terms of usage) come from prepositions, not adverbs. Maybe they're talking about how many Latin prepositions seem to go back to PIE adverbs? But that's certainly not true within Latin itself.

Answer (score 2):

The set of forms in Latin that can be used both as prepositions and as prefixes to verbs is fairly fixed (including things like *in, ad, dē, ex/ē,* etc.). You can consider these prefixes to be what linguists call a "closed class", meaning that as a practical matter, new ones were not regularly being derived by the time period of historical Latin. So a question like "Can a prefix be derived from a preposition instead of an adverb?" is more of an etymological query than anything else.

From the standpoint of etymology, there is not a firm difference between prepositions and adverbs in Latin. Many words, including *praeter,* can be used as either. The traditional distinction is that a word is a preposition when it takes a noun phrase as its "complement" (and "governs" a specific case for that noun phrase), whereas it is an adverb when it is used without taking any complement. Aside from the difference in grammatical function, prepositions and adverbs differ in Latin in a certain aspect of pronunciation: prepositions "depend on" the following word more strongly than other words, and so generally do not have their own independent accent in Latin, whereas adverbs are accented like an independent word.

Many Latin prepositions, including *[praeter](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/praeter),* can also be used as adverbs with no change in form (aside from the difference in accent). Other prepositions, such as *ad,* generally cannot be used without an accompanying noun in historical Latin, but are thought to etymologically derive from words with adverbial function.

I'm used to calling verb prefixes such as *ad-* "prepositional prefixes", but unlike true prepositions, these prefixes do not take a noun (phrase) as their complement (although the compound verb may itself take a complement, that is governed by the verb as a whole and does not necessarily take the same case that the preposition does when used by itself). So it does seem accurate to say that, even though the prefixes have the same form as prepositions, they are not functioning grammatically as prepositions when used in this manner.

Whether it's helpful to say that the function is, instead, that of an adverb is something I'm not totally sure of. I think "adverb" is widely regarded a bit of a grab-bag category of speech that covers a number of distinguishable functions; in English grammar, there have been some efforts at recategorizing things that were traditionally regarded as adverbs as "intransitive prepositions".

Draconis suggested, in a comment, that the analysis of the verb prefixes as adverbs could be viewed as a historical explanation. If it helps you to think of it that way, I don't see an issue with it, but I don't think the question of "how [to] figure out from which part of speech (prep. or adv.)" a prefix comes from is necessarily very useful or answerable. Rather than thinking of them as coming from *either* prepositions *or* adverbs, I think it's fine to think of them as prefixes and leave it at that (they are obviously related in meaning to the prepositions and adverbs of identical form, but I don't think this necessarily means we have to say that the prefixes are "really" one or the other of preposition vs. adverb).

As for the bases to which the prefixes like *ad-, dē-, ex-/ē-* are attached, the most productive pattern is for them to be attached to verbs, forming new words that are compound verbs, as described in your quote. Attachment of prepositional prefixes to nouns or adjectives is less frequent (although there are examples, e.g. in adjectives such as *ēlinguis* from *ē-* and *lingua* or *dēfōrmis* from *dē-* and *fōrma*). Whether or how a prefix is combined with noun or adjective bases is I think best analyzed on a case-by-case basis; I don't think it's helpful to bring the idea of the prefix's original part of speech into it.